Help what's the name of a Three Kings-ish WW2 movie (Not Kellys Heroes)?
I'm looking for a  movie from the early to late 00s, set during WW2.
So end of the war, France after D-Day, our "heroes" are german deserters who want to clean out one of the SS goldstashes and then fly into Switzerland to live out their days in style. Problem 1: The SS is on their way to secure the gold, so is Patton.
The movie is very Three Kingsy by mixing comedy, heist movie and serious war.

The Last Drop (wiki), 2005
British commandos sent to retrieve art and gold, competing with German deserters and the SS to get it during Operation Market Garden. Pretty much "The Monuments Men" vs. "Three Kings".
